Help Center Upgrade: How do we feel about the word "Plausible" and its synonyms?
Before I get going into deeper policy questions, I need a good referendum on how we feel toward the word "plausible" and any of its synonyms (realistic, possible, "as real as possible," etc.).
We've had sporadic debate in Meta over whether or not we should allow people to ask questions with the intent of making their fiction factual. In other words, they're not interested in rationalizing (e.g.) a 100-meter dragon in their imaginary world, they want to know (usually with considerable detail) how to make that dragon exist in the real world.1
The argument (as I remember) pro was making a fantasy something as realistic as possible is as much worldbuilding as anything else. Honestly, it's hard to argue against that.
The argument (as I remember) con was how unrealistic the question becomes because the more fanciful the idea the OP is trying to crowbar "realistically" into the Real World the more magic is required to make it happen — which is an answer the OP generally doesn't want to hear, as if they feel strongly that an answer to the question exists if they can just find the one person on Earth who knows it.
I could be wrong, but I believe the goal of whatever policy we come up with should be to encourage creative worldbuilding by helping users understand when they can embrace "reality" and when they need to embrace imagination.
Additionally, I wonder sometimes if the user really is asking for help realizing a completely fantastic idea, or if they're really asking "is this believable?" in a world that's increasingly "as real as possible" crazy such that they no longer understand the value of an imagination in the pursuit of science?
Question: What is the community's feelings concerning questions that ask if something is plausible, realistic, possible, or any other synonym?
Answers in support of "we want questions of that type!" should explain the difference between a good "plausible" and a bad "plausible" question.
Why does this matter?
Eventually I'm going to ask about the real world question debate. I believe that discussion will be muddied if we don't have a clear idea about this one first.

1 One of my earliest questions was of this type and was answered by L.Dutch. I was intrigued by the answer and asked for more details. I've never forgotten his response, "If I had a more detailed description for the above, I would file it to a patent office, not to WorldBuilding." That phrase has guided me when dealing with "Plausible" questions and I submit it as something to consider for this discussion. Where do we draw the line between good and bad "plausible" questions? What are the OP's expectations? Because expecting details to the level of being conceivably patentable make the question a waste of everyone's time. And yet rationalizing based on Real World concepts may leave the OP feeling unfulfilled. And it doesn't help that the OP may not have the education needed to judge the answers.

Users who wish to follow the Help Center Upgrade process more closely should roll their mouse over the official 2024-hc-redesign tag, above, or click this [tag:2024-hc-redesign] link and click the "Watch Tag" button.

WorldBuilding is a question-and-answer site. For it to work, the questions should have objective answers.
We have good hard science and science-based categories.
I do not think we can have a plausible category. Fiction is plausible when it is a tale well told. It can do this by being factually correct, but it can also do this by leaving out awkward details. H.G.Wells never said how the Time Machine worked, but his description of what it was like to travel in time let us willingly suspend our belief. The Death Star is magnificent cinema, even if a planet-sized craft that blows up planets might make little tactical sense. Dragons are huge, fly, and breath fire; deal with it. If someone asks "Is this plausible?", someone else can reply "Yes, if you write it well enough".
We do not reply "Yes, if you write it well enough" in WorldBuilding. What remains of the question that we can reply? We could point out internal inconsistencies, or alternative strategies that might improve the plot. We can offer alternatives. We might even suggests things that could be dropped or skilfully not mentioned: if the other elements and alloys in Middle-Earth are familiar, what is mithril?
Maybe we should use the term self-consistent rather than plausible.

"self-consistent" is not straight replacement of "plausible". Mostly because a lot of times users just present something without much, if any, related mechanics to it. Then ask "is it plausible". If we change the word, then it instantly becomes unanswerable because "is  self-consistent" without any other things to be consistent with cannot be answered. With that said, we do have a tag for consistency. Namely [[tag:internal-consistency]]. It does require supporting information to measure the consistency to.

I did not propose 'self-consistent' as a straight replacement of 'plausible'. 'Plausible' and 'believable' depend on how the idea is presented. You can have plausible physics under 'science-based'. A fantasy world can hang together, without plausible physics. If physics is not the reference, what is? It must be internally consistent. It may have to be consistent with other fantasy works. There must be a better term than 'self-consistent' but I have not come up with it.

Stack Exchange requires objective answers. Worldbuilding frequently does not and often can not.

I am stuck for a good word. I liked 'convincing' but that is just the same, really. We want something that means the premise is consistent with (a) itself, (b) other works in the genre, (c) physics as extended by the premise. This might allow 100-metre flying dragons (aircraft can fly, they can be magic), but not Flat Earth (unless you can say what happens at the edge). If there is no suitable word, we may have to forge our own.

They are very imperfect synonyms
Plausible means believable, or, for those readers with a better classical education, worthy of appreciation. Possible means just possible, as in not absolutely impossible. Realistic is more complicated; it may mean similar to reality, or it may mean apparently similar to reality.
I have this feeling that many questions apparently intended to ask for verisimilitude, but their authors either did not know the word, which would be strange for people who are interested in building fictional worlds, or more likely they chose to avoid it as being too Latinate. Which is equally strange, as the other three words are also adopted from Latin.
The reality is that this entire semantic field is a mess. There is no word with the clear meaning of showing the apperance of truth or reality without necessarily being true of faithful to the real world; not even verisimilar has this unequivocal meaning.
And the situation is exacerbated by the international nature of this site. There are vastly more people who have English as a second language than there are native speakers, and the Englishes native speakers speak are all different. English as she is wrote in actual practice has acquired some of the attributes of auxiliary languages such as Esperanto, not the least important of which is that users unconsciously assign to English words some parts of the meanings of similar or corresponding words in their own native languages. For example, the original Roman "worthy of admiration" meaning of the word plausible is very much alive in the Italian word plausibile; and the French equivalent of the English verisimilar is vraisemblable, a word which does not have even the slightest implication of not really true.
Here is an excerpt from my old edition of the Oxford Thesaurus:

likely adj.

probable, liable, expected: Three o’clock is the likely arrival time.
probable, conceivable, reasonable, credible, plausible, tenable: It seemed likely that Holmes would solve the case.
fitting, able, suitable, probable, seemly, meet, right, proper, qualified, acceptable, appropriate, apposite; favourite, odds-on, favoured, promising: Peters is the likely man for the job.
disposed to, apt to, inclined to, liable to: It’s likely to rain. You’re likely to think me mad, but I have my reasons for going.


So, then, how I understand those words?
When a "questions asks if something is plausible, realistic, possible, or any other synonym", my reaction depends on the word used, namely:

Is this possible?
If the question is good and well-structured, I would answer the question if I can without any qualms or hesitation.
If the question is not good and well-structured, most usually being written as if the word possible meant likely, my first reaction is to add a comment asking the author to please edit the question and explain what makes them believe that the thing would be impossible.

Is this plausible?
My first reaction in all cases is to add a comment explaining that plausibility depends strictly on the skill of the story-teller and has nothing to do with the physicality or with the rationality of the content of the story. When Homer describes how the blonde sorceress Circe lured the companions of Ulysses to their doom and transformation into pigs, the scene is perfectly plausible in the context of the story; but then Homer was a highly skilled story-teller.

Is this realistic?
I take the use of the word realistic to mean that the question asks about a world which is fundamentally similar to the real world and it expects an answer based on the current understanding of physics and chemistry and biology and so on.
My pet peeve is with questions which describe a world which has magic in it and then ask whether something or other is realistic. There is magic in the world; nothing about that world is even remotely realistic.


But in the end it is almost always all useless
The feeling of realism or irrealism is a feeling. It is the author who chooses what feeling they want to transmit to their readers. The basic rule is that if the author wants to transmit a feeling of other-worldliness they should limit their descriptions to general indications, letting the imagination of the reader run wild and color the world; and if the author wants to transmit the feeling of reality they should add mundane quantitative details, so that the reader feels that the description is true to life, whatever that life may be.
If you want to be realistic, just add specific details as they would be observed by an observer who was there. The more specific details you add, the more concrete the fictional world appears.
Dessert
A short extract from the delicious short story In the Year 2889 by (most likely) Michel Verne, the wayward son of the famous Jules. Note how everything is completely unrealistic but how it is made real by the confidence of the story-teller. You can read the entire short story at Project Gutenberg.
The idea is that the rise of cheap and universal direct audiovisual communication to the consumers has led to the emergence of a supremely powerful news organization, the Earth Chronicle. Silly, isn't it?

Yes, all these wonders have been wrought by the accumulator and the transformer. And can we not to them also trace, indirectly, this latest wonder of all, the great "Earth Chronicle" building in 253d Avenue, which was dedicated the other day? If George Washington Smith, the founder of the Manhattan "Chronicle," should come back to life to-day, what would he think were he to be told that this palace of marble and gold belongs to his remote descendant, Fritz Napoleon Smith, who, after thirty generations have come and gone, is owner of the same newspaper which his ancestor established!
For George Washington Smith's newspaper has lived generation after generation, now passing out of the family, anon coming back to it. When, 200 years ago, the political center of the United States was transferred from Washington to Centropolis, the newspaper followed the government and assumed the name of Earth Chronicle. Unfortunately, it was unable to maintain itself at the high level of its name. Pressed on all sides by rival journals of a more modern type, it was continually in danger of collapse. Twenty years ago its subscription list contained but a few hundred thousand names, and then Mr. Fritz Napoleon Smith bought it for a mere trifle, and originated telephonic journalism.
Every one is familiar with Fritz Napoleon Smith's system—a system made possible by the enormous development of telephony during the last hundred years. Instead of being printed, the Earth Chronicle is every morning spoken to subscribers, who, in interesting conversations with reporters, statesmen, and scientists, learn the news of the day. Furthermore, each subscriber owns a phonograph, and to this instrument he leaves the task of gathering the news whenever he happens not to be in a mood to listen directly himself. As for purchasers of single copies, they can at a very trifling cost learn all that is in the paper of the day at any of the innumerable phonographs set up nearly everywhere.
Fritz Napoleon Smith's innovation galvanized the old newspaper. In the course of a few years the number of subscribers grew to be 85,000,000, and Smith's wealth went on growing, till now it reaches the almost unimaginable figure of $10,000,000,000. This lucky hit has enabled him to erect his new building, a vast edifice with four façades, each 3,250 feet in length, over which proudly floats the hundred-starred flag of the Union. Thanks to the same lucky hit, he is to-day king of newspaperdom; indeed, he would be king of all the Americans, too, if Americans could ever accept a king. You do not believe it? Well, then, look at the plenipotentiaries of all nations and our own ministers themselves crowding about his door, entreating his counsels, begging for his approbation, imploring the aid of his all-powerful organ. Reckon up the number of scientists and artists that he supports, of inventors that he has under his pay.


Obligatory English Lesson: This Means You!

First, let's get our terms straight!

The word possible means that a thing is capable of existing, that it may be, that it might occur, that it might be done.
The word plausible means that a thing is seemingly valid, apparently likely, it is worthy of approbation or is seemingly right.
The word realistic means a representation of some thing as it actually is or was

As we can see, the difference is one of substance vs form. One is the actual, the other is the seeming. I would suggest that neither of these words ought to be seen by us worldbuilders as necessarily matters of "realism". They are not bound to what is either possible or plausible in the real world.

The distinction I see between these words is akin to hard science vs science based. Hard science relies on data, and so Questions of Possibility ought to focus more on well formed ideas, things that already exist in world and fairly narrow & high functioning queries.

Science based isn't so exacting, and so Questions of Plausibility ought to focus more on aesthetics and comparatives, on likelihoods given criteria.

In my experience, generally, when querents here use the word "plausible", they don't really mean "realistic" or "as real as possible". Here is an example question Is a Religion that Rejects the God Plausible that asks about plausibility.

This OP is working on a world and seems to have put some thought into several aspects of the divine and of mythology. He's laying out various facts of his world. In my opinion, this is not a question of plausibility but one of possibility. Is this a thing that can even be? Does this make sense? Basically he's asking if a religion can exist that denies its own nature and its own frame of reference.

A Question of Plausibility might be something like: is it plausible for a Buddhist like religion to have gods? Here we'd have to understand something about general Buddhism, that it is a non-theistic religious system. We would base our answer on that understanding.

ANSWER:  I am of the opinion that we should allow questions of both possibility and plausibility, as rightly understood. We should also entertain simple questions of "can I have ... given ..." as well as the questions that ask for excruciating detail. We should also entertain questions of "realism" --- "is it realistic to have a dog the size and power of a bear?" Of course, we should always entertain these questions within the context of worldbuilding!

We might have to settle for the fact that someone wants a 100 foot long dragon in the real world; but we have to approach such querents from our own perspective. They can't have a 100 foot long dragon in the real world, but we can damn well give them the best dragon in the multiverse for their fictional world!

The argument (as I remember) pro was making a fantasy something as realistic as possible is as much worldbuilding as anything else. Honestly, it's hard to argue against that.


I concur with this 100%.

The argument (as I remember) con was how unrealistic the question becomes because the more fanciful the idea the OP is trying to crowbar "realistically" into the Real World the more magic is required to make it happen — which is an answer the OP generally doesn't want to hear, as if they feel strongly that an answer to the question exists if they can just find the one person on Earth who knows it.


Here, we simply need to remind the querent that we don't do real world questions (okay, you now know my answer to your next question!) and we don't pretend like something fantasy can exist in the real world as we know it. We therefore have to be clear with these clients that we'll come up with anything, but it's always going to be from within a fictional context.

Sometimes people just have to be told no.

whatever policy we come up with should be to encourage creative worldbuilding by helping users understand when they can embrace "reality" and when they need to embrace imagination.


And presumably when they should be embracing both!
